# ElectronJS - Read another app's contents like the web contents of an unrelated Chrome Window

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, electron, fetch

I'm trying to have my electron app read a web page's contents that is loaded into a typical web browser like Chrome that has no relation with my electron app.

Is this natively possible right now? If not, what's an efficient solution to implement this and get data back in JSON?

Comment: Simplest solution is to write a chrome extension that pulls your browser data and puts then in a folder, this folder can then be read by electron via the main process (NodeJS).

Comment: For the general usecase it is not possible. Chrome sandboxes each tab, so there is no way to read that out except via fiddling with the memory of chrome. And that is a hard thing to pull off and would require a native node module or some native software in between the browser and your electron app.